# Windows service to automate a job

Tags: javascript, c#, automation, windows-services

I am trying to automate**strong text** a certain task and the procedure of it is as follows:

1. Open web browser (Google Chrome)
2. Go to a certain site
3. Put in username then jump to another field (like **pressing the Tab
           button**.. it automatically log ins since I am connected to the
           office network)
4. Type again on a certain field
5. Click search button etc etc

Is it **better to code a windows service**? Are there any *other ways* to do the above task? I wanted to automate it because the job is just more about **Click, Type, Click, and Wait**. The values are also somehow **fixed** so it could really be automated.

Comment: If you don't have too many dynamic input values and your automation threshold is within manageable limit then you can create a simple Windows Task/Service. If the automation requires heavy input data and is dynamic in nature and the threshold increases, you might have to go through a more complex architecture.

Comment: What did you mean by 'more complex architecture'? Any specific suggestions? And also what is your definition of a 'manageable limit'? Thank you very much!

Comment: I mean how frequently you trigger the automation and the time taken for the automation to complete one cycle. So let's say- your one automation cycle completes in 2 minutes and you trigger it every 30 minutes, with 10 automation cycles. This is manageable. Now, if you increase the cycles or completion time, the automation would not be completed within the 30 minutes stipulated time. So, you might now implement Threading, multiple task schedulers or some queue management to make it faster.

Comment: My current code is in Web Forms. Can my button click function trigger a Windows Service that would perform the job?